# Flutter PARAMS on Get http

Tags: http, flutter, dart

How to Put a PARAMS on GET function, 
I did not find anything in the documentation of the dart or flutter about this

```
String url = 'xxxxxx';

Future<String> makeRequest() async {

Map params = {
  "anunciante_name"
  "anunciante_pass"
  "anunciante_email"
};

var _body = jsonDecode(params);

var response = await http
.get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Content-type": "application/json", "key": "xxxxx", "token": "xxxxx"},);

print(response.body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the `get` method of the `http`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html) object,

```dart
Future<Response> get (dynamic url, {Map<String, String> headers})
```

the second parameter is the `headers`. You can pass each parameter of yours to it as a  value the same way you pass your `key`, `token` and `Content-Type`

```dart
Map<String, String> reqHeaders = {
    "Content-type": "application/json", 
    "key": "xxxxx", 
    "token": "xxxxx", 
    "anunciante_name":name,
    "anunciante_pass":password,
    "anunciante_email":email
};

var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url), {headers: reqHeaders});
```

Comment: you save me... 1 more question... 
every time I try to use response.statusCode == 200 it says that statusCode is not a variable I try to create but it is still an error, and in the internet examples nobody defined a variable statusCode they just used it as if it were something native to dart

Comment: Okay @EricMontelares, I would have to see your code for that. Receiving a response object with a `statusCode` property attached to it is not dependent on your Flutter/frontend code. The server api attaches the `statusCode`. Check the api docs of the api to see if a `statusCode` property is attached to the response. Also check if an `ok` property is attached to the response. Sometimes, an `ok` property with a value of `true` or `false` is attached to the response instead of a `statusCode` of 200

Comment: I already decided, it was something really like you said, thanks for everything again